# where should I place thermistor on lithium battery?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, circuit-protection, thermistor

I am going to use ICR18650-26J Li-ion battery, MCP73833 charging IC and BQ29733 battery protection IC.

Comment: Wherever you want to measure the temperature of the battery the most effectively

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know that effective place? Or I can place it anywhere?

Comment: I have seen a tear-down of a battery charger (can't remember where apart from "youtube") which had the temperature sensor on one of the contacts to the cell, *probably* the negative side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its going to make little difference where you place the thermistor on the battery, however the more material you have between the thermistor and the battery the more thermal resistivity you will have.

If you can put it next to the foil you will measure the battery temperature better (less thermal resistivity from heatshrink that normally comes on the li-ion packs). Most applications measure battery temperature for thermal runaway reasons so if the battery is getting hot, its going to get hot everywhere.